# Access to an object property in a list within a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, ip, client-server

I have a problem that I can't resolve by myself.

I have an ObservableCollection of "product" with a "price" property.
Every second, the price of every products change. This is my server part.
I have a window, with some textbox, which bind on the price property.

In an other part, I have a client. The client needs to get the price of all products.

So, first, my client connect to my server (no problem here). it sends a message to server, server receives it.

My problem is here : the value of the price property change every second, but in my thread, I can't get the new values...

Here my code :
   - Product :

```
private volatile float price;
public float Price
{
    get { return price; }
    set
    {
        price = value;
        notifyPropertyChanged("Price");
    }
}

public Product(int time)
{
    timer = new Timer(time);
    timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
    timer.Start();
}

void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Price++;
}
```

- my server :

  ```
  private ObservableCollection<product> listGroupProduct;
  public MainWindow()
  {
      Thread thread;
      InitializeComponent();
      this.DataContext = this;

      // Create the server
      thread = new Thread(() => createServer(ref listGroupProduct));
      thread.Start();
  }
  public static void createServer(ref ObservableCollection<Product> list)
  {
      string client = "";
      try
      {
          IPAddress ipAdress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.50");
          TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAdress, 1220);

          listener.Start();
          socket = listener.AcceptSocket();

          // Receive client name
          client = ReceiveMessage(100);
          MessageBox.Show("New client connected : " + client);

          // Send number of products
          SendMessage(list.Count.ToString());

          // Get articles request from a client
          ReceiveMessage(8);

          // Send all articles
          while (true)
          {
              for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
              {
                  if (articlesString != "")
                      articlesString += "|";
                  articlesString += list[i].Price + ";";
              }
              byte[] bytes = new byte[list.Count * 50];
              bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(articlesString.ToCharArray());
              socket.Send(bytes);
          }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
      }
  }

  private static void SendMessage(string p)
  {
      byte[] bytes = new byte[p.Length];
      bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(p.ToCharArray());

      socket.Send(bytes);
  }

  private static string ReceiveMessage(int p)
  {
      string tmp = "";

      byte[] b = new byte[p];
      int k = socket.Receive(b);
      for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
          tmp += Convert.ToChar(b[i]);

      return tmp;
  }
  ```

My client :

```
private StreamSocket streamSocket;
public string Server = "192.168.1.89";
public int Port = 1220;

IInputStream inputStream;
IOutputStream outputStream;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    CreateSocket();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    SendMessage("articles");
    toto.Text = "Message send : articles";

    GetAllArticles();
}

private async void GetAllArticles()
{
    toto.Text = await GetMessage(50);
    toto.Text = "Waiting articles...";
    toto.Text = await GetMessage(articlesNumber * 50));
}

private async Task CreateConnection()
{
    SendMessage("tablet");
    toto.Text = "message send : tablet";

    articlesNumber = int.Parse(await GetMessage(1));
    toto.Text = "Number articles : " + articlesNumber.ToString();
}

private async void CreateSocket()
{
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

    streamSocket = new StreamSocket();
    await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(new HostName(Server), Port.ToString());

    inputStream = streamSocket.InputStream;
    outputStream = streamSocket.OutputStream;

    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;

    // Envoi du nom et réception du nombre d'articles
    await CreateConnection();

     // Réception de tous les articles chaque secondes
    SendMessage("tablet");
    timer.Start();
}

private async void SendMessage(string message)
{
    IBuffer buffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(message, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
    await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer);
}

private async Task<string> GetMessage(int size)
{
    byte[] tmp = new byte[size];
    IBuffer buffer1 = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(tmp);

    toto.Text = "Waiting message... (size : " + size.ToString() + ")";
    await inputStream.ReadAsync(buffer1, (uint)size, InputStreamOptions.None);
    toto.Text = "Message received !";

    return CryptographicBuffer.ConvertBinaryToString(BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8, buffer1);
}
```

(By the way : "toto" is a textbox I use for debug :) )

Have you an idea why my client receive well the first value, but when, on my server side, the value change, my client continue to get the same value and not the new one ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the server has infinite loop and keeps resending same data over and over again.  CreateServer has the infinite loop immediately after the "Send all articles" comment.

Comment: Yes i know, but I don't know how to change it. I want my server send the news datas, not the same all the time.

Comment: your server needs a receive thread, and after the receive thread receives a complete message, it needs to send the appropriate response.

Comment: I understand it. But the problem is the same : How can i get value of the list within this thread ?